# nrows alternative for read_sql_table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am a reading an sql table like this - I don't see an "nrows" option for `read_sql_table()` as there is for `read_csv()`. Then how else can I read only a small amount of rows from the data set? Let's say 100.

```
df['table'] = pd.read_sql_table('table', engine, schema_z2,
                                    columns = cols)
```

I know about chunksize but from what I understand, it is used for reading the table in parts, and not to just limit the number of rows you read

Comment: use `read_sql_query` and embed a select statement in there, with your limit

Answer (score 0):

add `chunksize`

```
df['table'] = pd.read_sql_table('table', engine, schema_z2,
                                    columns = cols, chunksize=100)
```

> If specified, returns an iterator where chunksize is the number of rows to include in each chunk.